# OpenCV memory leak

Tags: qt, opencv, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I need help with openCV. System: WinXP, OpenCV 2.4.7.2, QT 5.2.1. I have problem with memory leak. When this function starts, and about 2min i have an error like this:"std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0012a9e8...

```
void EnclosingContour(IplImage* _image){

    assert(_image!=0);
    //Clone src image and convert to gray
    clone_image = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(_image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvConvertImage(_image, clone_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    //Some images for processing
    dst = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(_image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    temp = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(_image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    //Make ROI
    if (ui.chb_ROI->isChecked()){
        cvSetImageROI(clone_image, cvRect(ui.spb_x1->value(), ui.spb_y1->value(),ui.spb_x2->value(),ui.spb_y2->value()));}
    //Create image for processing
    bin = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(clone_image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    bin = cvCloneImage(clone_image);
    //Canny before
    if (ui.chb_canny_before->isChecked()){
        cvCanny(bin, bin, ui.hsl_threshold_1->value(), ui.hsl_threshold_2->value());
    }
    //Adaptive threshold
    if (Adaptive==true){
        cvAdaptiveThreshold(bin, dst, ui.hsl_adaptive->value(), 0, 0, 3, 5);
        bin = cvCloneImage(dst);
        cvReleaseImage(&dst);
    }
    //Morphology operations
    if (morphology==true){
        cvMorphologyEx(bin, bin, temp, NULL, operations, 1);
        cvReleaseImage(&temp);
    }
    //Canny after
    if (ui.chb_canny_after->isChecked()){
        cvCanny(bin, bin, ui.hsl_threshold_1->value(), ui.hsl_threshold_2->value());
    }
    //Zero ROI
    cvZero(clone_image);
    cvCopyImage(bin, clone_image);
    cvResetImageROI(clone_image);
    //Show
        cvNamedWindow( "bin", 1 );
         cvShowImage("bin", clone_image);
    cvReleaseImage(&clone_image);
    //storage for contours
        storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
        contours=0;
    // find contours
    if (ui.chb_ROI->isChecked()){
        int contoursCont = cvFindContours(bin, storage,&contours,sizeof(CvContour),CV_RETR_LIST,method,cvPoint(ui.spb_x1->value(), ui.spb_y1->value()));
    }else
    {
        int contoursCont = cvFindContours(bin, storage,&contours,sizeof(CvContour),CV_RETR_LIST,method,cvPoint(0,0));
    }
    assert(contours!=0);
    //How many contours
    // All contours
    for(CvSeq* current = contours; current != NULL; current = current->h_next ){

            //Draw rectangle over all contours
            CvRect r = cvBoundingRect(current, 1);
            cvRectangleR(_image, r, cvScalar(0, 0, 255, 0), 3, 8, 0);
            //Show width of rect
            ui.textEdit_2->setText(QString::number(r.width));       
    }
    // Clean resources
    cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);
    cvReleaseImage(&bin);
```

}

Comment: Please refrain from cyrillic comments. They have no value on an English site, and they just bring noise.

Comment: Please refrain from using the outdated c-api. it's dead and gone. you'll only shoot into your foot using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are releasing 'temp' and 'dst' images inside 'if'. This is a sure recipe for memory leak, since they may not be released at all.

On a side note, you are using C interface of OpenCV which is deprecated and will be removed soon. If you switch to C++ interface (i.e. if you use Mat instead of IplImage*) than problem of memory leak because of unreleased image could not possibly happen.